# Can not to replace string

Tags: php, substring

The problem is related to php. I have a text in a variable say $text and some start position and end positions. How to inject the some substring on the specific position. the problem is that if i put some text in a specific position then position index changes and it will be difficult to put next sub string to the right place. Help me. thanks in advance.

```
function previewTxt($text,$topicid, $sectionid)
{

    $dbConn = new DBConnUtil();

        $queryString = "SELECT * from inline_topic_xref where TOPIC_ID=$topicid and SECTION_ID=$sectionid";
        $result = $dbConn->run_query($queryString);

                $newtext=$text;
                $count=0;
             while($row = $result->fetch_object())
             {

                $newtext = replace($newtext, "<a href='#'>" ,$row->REF_TEXT_START);
                $newtext = replace($newtext, "</a>" ,$row->REF_TEXT_END);

             }


           return $newtext; 
}


function replace($org_text,$str_rep, $position)
{
  $length=strlen($org_text);  
  $temp1=substr($org_text,0,$position);
  $temp2=substr($org_text,$position,$length);  
   $replaced =$temp1.$str_rep.$temp2;

   return $replaced;
}
```

Comment: Can you give a much more concrete example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: I have to inject '<a href='#'>'  and '<a/>' in a long text in some specific positions. the position is stored. but when i put <a href='#'> then the string length changes and difficult to put <a href='#'> or <a/> in other positions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried

```
substr_replace($oldstr, $str_to_insert, $pos, 0)
```

?

here is the documentation 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php